# Spring Security with Struts 2 - redirect to different page based on User Role

Tags: struts2, spring-security

I am able to authenticate the user from the database but there are different users in my app so I want to redirect them to their different homepages based on their Role.

The best way I guess would be by checking the user role in a struts action and then redirecting to appropriate page. But how do I do that. Does spring security set session variables storing authentication information.

If yes, then how do I access them in a struts action. Also how do I access the username and password after login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access [`Authentication`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) of the current user in any place during request processing as follows:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getSecuirtyContext().getAuthentication()
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative would be to do your routing within Spring Security itself by implementing your own AuthenticationSuccessHandler and wiring it into your Spring config.